# unable to pass the last installation step "cmake --build . --target INSTALL" oatpp

Tags: c++

am very new to this oatpp, i have been facing difficulties to get started with it because the only helped tool was the documentation...How ever i struggled to strickly follow the installation steps from the documentation but could not passed through them successfully. Here are the steps

1)$ git clone https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp.git
2)$ cd oatpp
3)$ MD build
4)$ cd build\

5)$ cmake ..
6)$ cmake --build . --target INSTAL

step 5 failed becaused the cmake generator is not specified in which i replaced it with: cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -B build . and it was successful

But step6 gave me the error: Error: could not load cache... That is where i got stucked...

I even skipped and tried to build the project (using play button vs code editor) and got the etror:

such file or directory
#include "oatpp/web/server/HttpProcessor.hpp" ....even though the file exist

NB am using Windows

I replaced the 5 command with cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -B build .
but tried to follow the last step and it fail

Comment: ***me the error: Error: could not load cache*** I expect you executed that from the wrong folder. There has to be a `CMakeCache.txt` file in the folder you execute that command.